# Return redirect url using jQuery (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect

I need to get the redirect url's for a list of 100 websites using javascript. For example wnbc.com is redirected to nbcnewyork.com. So this code below should return "nbcnewyork.com"

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://www.wnbc.com",
   dataType: "script",
   success: function (data, textstatus, xhrreq) {
    alert('You are now at URL: ' + xhrreq.getResponseHeader());
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot interact with content of other domains. An AJAX request cannot be made to a different domain and even if you had an < iframe src="http://www.wnbc.com" > your code wouldn't be capable of read the real URL from it.

So basically, what you're asking it's impossible to do with JavaScript in a browser.